# Desktop Environment that scales GUI according to DPI and monitor size

Tags: cinnamon, desktop-environment, resolution, multi-monitor

Does anyone know if there exists a DE that scales GUI based on DPI and monitor size? There's a 15" 4K laptop and 27" 4K monitor that I want to use side by side. My distribution of choice is Linux Mint with Cinnamon, but it clearly calculates the number of pixels to use for GUI elements based on the laptop screen size (or even hardcoded values maybe based on resolution and DPI) and uses those numbers regardless of what's the actual size of the monitor. So everything is almost twice as large on the 27" monitor. Are there other DEs that are better at this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Gnome + Wayland** support this. See [How to set per-monitor scaling on Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875832/how-to-set-per-monitor-scaling-on-wayland).

Note that  apps that use XWayland (most non-gnome & non-kde, like Firefox etc.) don't re-scale properly yet.

If a ratio of 2x does not work for you, There will soon be support for [fractional scaling](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2017/05/19/fractional-scaling-goes-east/) as well. It is [experimental](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/enable-fractional-scaling-gnome-linux) in Gnome 3.26.

*Alternatives*:

- Work on KDE + Wayland scaling is not as advanced right now AFAIK.
- Under X11, you can achieve something usable with some manual work with xrandr. See [Is it possible to have two different DPI configurations for two different screens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393400/is-it-possible-to-have-two-different-dpi-configurations-for-two-different-screen/555812#555812) or [Configuring mixed DPI monitors with xrandr](https://blog.summercat.com/configuring-mixed-dpi-monitors-with-xrandr.html)